# Error of the Zabbiks item when monitoring the ssl aws ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, zabbix

It is necessary with the help of Zabbiks to enable monitoring of SSL count licenses for ALB in aws.
Zabbiks can't recognize the item

`UserParameter = ssl.count, aws elbv2 describe-listener-certificates --listener-arn --profile ******** arn: aws: elasticloadbalancing: eu-central - ******* ****** 1dcfc52e | jq '.Certificates | . []. CertificateArn '| wc -l`

zabbix writes

`Value of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (unsigned)".Value "The config profile (****) could not be found0"`

If I change the Type of information to text, then everything works except for the triggers, which should return how many SSL licenses are in the ALB,
output from `zabbix_agentd -t ssl.count command ssl.count [t | 26]` everything works from the console, all credential are fine.

ABL in zabbix  declared in macros `{$ HOST.NAME}` `main-devs - *******. Eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Tell me who came across, what could it be?

Comment: This is strange: `Value "The config profile (****) could not be found0"` . Did you set the item without the `| wc -l`, then added it a few minutes later? This could explain why the `zabbix_agentd -t` test works fine and returns 26

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni not at the very end, I added it all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that you are not redirecting the standard error, and your output is not a number. Since it's not a number, is not valid in a Numeric item.

Example:

```
$ ls -l temp.sh nonexisting.sh
ls: cannot access nonexisting.sh: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser domain users 14918 Oct 15  2019 temp.sh

$ ls -l temp.sh nonexisting.sh | wc -l
ls: cannot access nonexisting.sh: No such file or directory
1

$ ls -l temp.sh nonexisting.sh 2>/dev/null | wc -l
1
```

With your code:

```
UserParameter = ssl.count, aws elbv2 describe-listener-certificates --listener-arn --profile ******** arn: aws: elasticloadbalancing: eu-central - ******* ****** 1dcfc52e 2>/dev/null | jq '.Certificates | . []. CertificateArn '| wc -l
```